# How do I use Burn to bundle WiX installers? Can I make them both in a single project?

Tags: .net, wix, installation, bundle, burn

I've been stuck for a while with WiX/Burn lately. My intention is to create an installer that unpacks files and downloads .Net Framework if it is missing. As far as I'm concerned, I should use some kind of bundle tool, Burn, for the .Net part and "normal" WiX to unpack the files. I have written the unpacking part (using SharpDevelop) and now I'm ready to make a bundler for that. How should I merge the Burn and WiX stuff? Do I have to create two separate projects, one for the MSI and one for the bundle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you create one project for the `Bundle` and a separate project for the `MSI` package. Best to create a `ProjectReference` between the projects to ensure build order is correct.

Comment: Ah, then I can still link them together within the same solution. Thank you!